# Create round button with system image and tint in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm trying to create a round button with the ellipsis SFSymbol such that the ellipse is white with a circular background. I've tried 2 approaches as follows, one with the filled ellipse image and the other with regular ellipse.

The output I'm looking to achieve:

[image]

versus what I have at the moment:

[image]

With the first button, its all white (cannot seem to apply a tint plus foreground style as I thought) and with the second approach its no longer round (unless maybe I apply a clipshape maybe? but that seems too convoluted). Is there any way to achieve the output with `Button`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 50) {
            Button(action: {}, label: {
                Image(systemName: "ellipsis.circle.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 40)
            })
            .tint(.secondary)
            .foregroundStyle(.white)
            
            Button(action: {}, label: {
                Image(systemName: "ellipsis")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
            })
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
            .buttonBorderShape(.capsule)
            .tint(.secondary)
            .foregroundStyle(.white)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background {
            Color.black
                .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .all)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the border to be a circle, do `.buttonBorderShape(.circle)`, not `.buttonBorderShape(.capsule)`.

To better match the result you want, you can make the `frame` of the image smaller, but add some extra `padding`. For example,

```
 Button(action: {}, label: {
    Image(systemName: "ellipsis")
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFit()
        .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
        .padding(7.5)
})
.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
.buttonBorderShape(.circle)
.tint(.secondary)
.foregroundStyle(.white)
```

This produces:

[image]

If you need to support older versions of iOS, and `.circle` is not available, you can use a non-bordered button style, and add a circular background to the image instead:

```
Button(action: {}, label: {
    Image(systemName: "ellipsis")
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFit()
        .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
        .padding(7.5)
        .background(.secondary.opacity(0.5), in: Circle())
})
.buttonStyle(.plain)
.tint(.secondary)
.foregroundStyle(.white)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to set its background like below.

```
Button(action: {}, label: {
        Image(systemName: "ellipsis.circle.fill")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(width: 40, height: 40)         
         })
         .foregroundStyle(.gray) // Use color you want.
         .background {
              Circle()
                 .fill(Color.white)
         }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest moving the `.background` to the `Image` itself. This keeps the background the same size as the image, which is important if button shapes is turned on in the accessibility settings. It's also a good idea to add a small amount of padding to the background circle, so that the color of the background is not seen at the edges of the round image in the foreground: .padding(2) is enough.